Excel (for MacOS) VBA runtime error 1004 when running modified recorded macro
With Excel 365 for MAC/OS I get error 1004 (Excel cannot access xxxx.csv. The document may be read-only or encrypted.) after changing the file name in a recorded  VBA macro.
I receive .csv files (semicolon delimiter) from my bank and want to automate importing the data into worksheets. To that end, I recorded a macro while importing one of the files. The recording produced the following little function:
    Public Function openSource(fileToOpen As String) As Excel.Workbook
    'Open the csv file with semicolon delimiters

    
    
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= _
            "/Users/tttt/uuuuu/vvvv/wwwww/20240905.csv", Origin:= _
            65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False _
            , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
            Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
            Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array( _
            16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Function
`

This function works as expected if I do not change the file name from the one used during recording of the macro. If I change the file by editing the function, I get the the 1004 runtime error described above. If I rerecord the macro using the new file name, the new macro works as expected. Other than the different file names, the two macros appear identical to the naked eye.
The file is not read-only nor is it encrypted.
I tried to execute the macro with different file names and have the corresponding files read into an Excel sheet.
